# Git bash stuck on 'Is this okay? (yes)'

Tags: git-bash, npm-init

Every time I do `npm init` and hit enter until the question 'Is this okay? (yes)' pops out on which I answer 'yes', Git Bash gets stuck. This means that I can write anything, hit enter and all I get is a newline. By the way, a new `package.json` file is created in my dir. Also, everything works fine if I use the Windows cmd, and not Git Bash.

How do you confirm the question in Git Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be a compatibility issue with `npm` and `git-bash`

You can just terminate the process with `Ctrl + C` and you will see the package.json being created or else run the `init` command like

```
npm init -y
```